# How do I properly get the contents of input type="file"?

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

What I'm trying to achieve is have a button which allows the user to upload a text file so that its contents are copied into a `<textarea>` element.

I've got a working prototype ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g77xgre/)) using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), but I feel like my solution is poor / inefficient.

Here's a summed up version of what I'm doing:

---

When the user clicks the 'Open File' button, I create a hidden `input` element (`type="file"`) and attach an `onchange` event handler to it.

When this handler is called (i.e. user selected a file), it creates a `FileReader` instance and attaches a new handler to its `onloadend` event.

The `FileReader` handler, when called (i.e. when [`readAsText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) is done), then sets `textarea.value` to the [`result`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result) property of the `FileReader` instance.

---

Since I've never had any previous experience with this type of input, my question is:

Is this the 'correct' / recommended approach? In terms of performance, browser support and such, is there a 'better' way to do this?

Here's a snippet with the code from JSFiddle:

```js
document.getElementById("open-btn").onclick = function open_file() {
    let dialog = document.createElement("input");
    dialog.setAttribute("type", "file");
    dialog.style.display = "none";

    dialog.onchange = function() {
        if(this.files.length !== 1)
            return console.warn("Must select 1 file");

        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
            let current_file = document.querySelector(".selected");
            let editor = document.getElementById("editor");

            if(current_file == null)
                return console.warn("No selected elements");

            if("length" in current_file && current_file.length != 1)
                return console.warn("Multiple selected elements");

            if(editor == null)
                return console.warn("No editor found");

            editor.value = this.result;
        }
        reader.readAsText(this.files[0]);
        document.body.removeChild(this);
    }
    
    document.body.appendChild(dialog);
    dialog.click();
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: middle;
    list-style: none;
}
textarea {
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    word-break: break-all;
    border: 1px solid #aeaeae;
    background-color: #fff;
    resize: none;
    overflow-wrap: normal;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: pre;
}
button {
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 1px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #b0ccff;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 cornflowerblue;
    transition: all .1s ease;
    margin: 5px;
}
button:active {
    transform: translateY(3px);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0 cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="editor" class="selected"></textarea>
<button id="open-btn" onclick="open_file();"> Open File </button>
```

Comment: What is your end objective? Are you just trying to upload a file to the server? I am not exactly sure why you're wanting to read the file into a textbox.

Comment: @kyle The whole thing is a kind of code editor, so having the user be able to save and edit files from their machine is a huge plus. It'll stay on the client side so there's no need to upload it to a server (otherwise a `<form>` would do nicely)